# React not rendering components from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on trying to get a table drawn from an array in react and I can't seem to get it to work. Normally I get the data from a database, but to test it I'm just making the array myself so I know the data is good. I've tried surrounding my map code with a div and React.Fragment like in examples I've seen but still none of the array is rendered. All the other components render fine. I've been working on trying to fix this for hours, so any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './RankingsPage.css';
import AddGamePage from './AddGamePage'

class RankingsPage extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getHeadToHeadPage = this.getHeadToHeadPage.bind(this);
    this.updateTable = this.updateTable.bind(this);

    let tableData = [];
    this.state = {
      tableRows: tableData
    }

    let body = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    /*fetch('./GetRankings.php', body).then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => {
      if(json['Status'] === 'ConnectionError') {
        alert('Database Connection error! Please try again!');
      } else {
        for(let key in json['Rankings']){
          tableData.push({
            'Name': key,
            'Wins': json['Rankings'][key]['Wins'],
            'Losses': json['Rankings'][key]['Losses'],
            'Rank': json['Rankings'][key]['Rank']
          });
        }
        console.log(tableData);
        this.updateTable(tableData)
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert('File Connection Error! Please try again!');
      console.log(error);
    });*/
    tableData.push({'Name': 'Bob', 'Rank': 10, 'Wins': 3, 'Losses': 2});
    this.updateTable(tableData);
  }

  updateTable(tableData) {
    console.log(tableData);

    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {tableRows: tableData}
    });
    console.log("Updating: "+JSON.stringify(this.state.tableRows[0]['Name']));
  }

  getHeadToHeadPage(e) {
    this.props.changePage(<AddGamePage />);
  }

  render(){
    console.log('From render: '+this.state.tableRows);
    return(
      <center className = 'center'>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Score</th>
              <th>Wins</th>
              <th>Losses</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.tableRows.map((value, index) => {
              <tr key={index}>
                <td><a href='#' onClick = {this.getHeadToHeadPage}>{value['Name']}</a></td>
                <td>{value['Rank']}</td>
                <td>{value['Wins']}</td>
                <td>{value['Losses']}</td>
              </tr>
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
    );
  }
}

export default RankingsPage;
```

Comment: robinsax's answer is the reason nothing shows. In addition, there's a few other issues to note. Firstly, don't do API calls or execute `setState()` in your constructor. The constructor shouldn't have any side effects, use `componentDidMount()` to do that. Secondly, in your constructor, `tableData.push()` will also mutate the state, since you set it equal to `state.tableRows`. Don't mutate the state directly. Third, you're calling `console.log` after a `setState()` call, that won't work. `setState()` is asynchronous so won't reflect in the lines of code directly following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common mistake with React - your map callback isn't returning anything.

You can either explicitly return the `tr` or remove the curly braces around the function body, optionally replacing them with round ones for readability like so.

```
{this.state.tableRows.map((value, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
        <td><a href='#' onClick = {this.getHeadToHeadPage}>{value['Name']}</a></td>
        <td>{value['Rank']}</td>
        <td>{value['Wins']}</td>
        <td>{value['Losses']}</td>
    </tr>
   )
 )}
```